# Strings full of U+FFFD when doing replacement in Python

Tags: python, unicode

I've made a python script that replaces placeholder strings in HTML such as {content} with strings from a tuple. But, when written to a file, the strings are preceded by a Unicode replacement character where some of the replacements start, but not others.

[image: Example]

What could be causing this and how can I remove/prevent them?

Update: I've fixed the problem by removing a leading space between the colon and placeholder string, but still don't know why this happened. Perhaps someone can explain?

Comment: Can you include the code that you fixed, before and after the fix?

Comment: The code is just Python's native string.replace()

Comment: It'd be helpful to see the actual code surrounding the problem and the fix, if you'd like the community to try and diagnose the original problem. With what you've shared so, there's just not enough information to make a conclusion.